Use native windows dll with jni in android studio for composables previewing
Android studio's preview feature for composables is clearly useful.The problem is that it runs in windows natively and so all jni code one uses for android won't work.
I've been trying to get something very simple to work for the last 5 hours and through the trouble have realized that loadLibrary will load only windows dll's(not .so files) and that one can load windows dll's.
E.g., if you take the simple native C++ hello world project you will not be able to call the native function from a composable because 1. the library won't be loaded. 2. Even if it could it is a so for linux and not windows. Hence there is no way to "preview" native code.
In some cases this is desirable so one can have a consistent experience between the preview and android native. E.g., ideally we could compile the jni c++ code into a windows dll rather than a so and everything work just fine.
One of the problem is that using loadLibrary seems to be constantly loaded every time the composable is recomposed and this throws and except preventing any further testing to see if I can get native windows functions to be called in the preview.
    @Preview()
    @Composable
    fun MainActivityPreview() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().load("jnitest.dll")
        var s = testJNI("fdadf")
    }


where testJNI is both in the jnitest.cpp for windows and the android jni cpp file(They should essentially mimic each other the best one can get.
running this code gives the error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library jnitest.dll already loaded in another classloader
My guess is once the library is loaded it stays resident in memory and is not unloaded until I close the entire process.
Is there a better way to develop native windows dll's that can be used in these android apps for a consistent experience?
E.g., for my use case I want to write a native resampling function and then see the results in preview without having to run the app on the emulator or mock it up on preview. One cpp file would be optimal and have it combine to the different binaries. This would get me what I want. I'd maintain two versions though if necessary.
Another reason I want to do this is to be able to load pdf's into the previwer.
android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer
Cannot take a file, even if it is copied to a tmp directory. It can take an integer file descriptor but not a java FileDescriptor. I don't know why it fails but I was hoping to get the native file descriptor and pass that to PdfRenderer and get it to load the pdf's. (this is what let me on the chase to realize that jni's did not execute inside preview)
